# How to get the assets root path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I know [image_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag), which returns a html tag for a resource. If no absolute path is given, the resource is mounted under `assets`.

How to this assets root path? I want to avoid using a hard-coded `File.join('assets','other_resource')` in my application.

Comment: Did you tried `asset_path()`?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for, exactly, is unclear...

But, Assuming you want the relative path to an image asset, you can use [`image_path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_path):

```
image_path("other_resource.png") # => /assets/other_resource.png
```

If you want the absolute path to the image asset, you can use [`image_url`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-image_url):

```
image_url("other_resource.png") # => http://example.com/assets/other_resource.png
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do:

```
File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets','other_resource')
```

but I usually prefer:

```
asset_path
```

You can use [asset_path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb) from your CSS and JS too: i.e.

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```